# libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.26 but running with 1.5.2

Tags: macos, r, libpng

I have a problem on my mac when trying in R to produce png images.

I am getting this warnings:

`libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.2.26 but running with 1.5.2`

I am running the R 2.14 version using the R-studio GUI.

I am not excatly sure about the libpng problem. When I am doing locate libpng-config I'm getting several hits, some with libong-config12, some with libpng-config14, some without nay numbers:

`ayeroslaviz:~ ayeroslaviz$ locate libpng-config`
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/libpng-config`
`/Library/Frameworks/GTK+.framework/Versions/2.18.X11/Resources/bin/libpng-config`
`/opt/local/bin/libpng-config`
`/usr/X11/bin/libpng-config`
`/usr/local/bin/libpng-config`

When doing which `libpng-config` I'm getting: `/usr/local/bin/libpng-config`

Is there a way to uninstall older versions of libpng or update the paths to the right version. Unfortunately I am not even sure, what thesource of this warning, so I hope I gave here all the needed information.

I would be grateful for anyone who gives me a hint about how to solve this problem.

thanks

A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, you're using a Mac, so there's a simpler (but not documented) method.

```
quartz.save('my_filename.png', type='png')
```

Note that the image you want to save must be the currently active quartz window.

Comment: it help me a lot to save the files, but I am still wonering, what the hell is happenning with my mac, so that I am not able to create any png files over R.

Answer (score 0):

If your code still works, then don't worry about it.  The fact this this is a warning rather than an error message means that there *might* be a problem, not that there definitely is a problem.  IF you don't want to see the warning, wrap your R code in a call to `suppressMessages`.

```
suppressMessages(code_to_call_libpng)
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. the code creates the png files, but they have Zero KB. They are empty.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could occur because RStudio (or some other library you are using in your project) is using in-built libpng libraries (v1.2) and when the application run, the version installed in the system is v1.5: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngfaq.html#mismatch. If this is the point, you could try to upgrade RStudio libpng libraries or downgrade system libpng ones.